How to disable Proguard
i want to disable proguard completly but i cant find a way to disable it
setting minify enable to false has no effect
 buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isCrunchPngs = false
            //proguardFiles(
              //  getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            //)
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
        }
    }

i tried to disable R8 in gradle properties but its not possible to use it in AGP 7+ and useProguard = false is also the same

Using isMinifyEnabled is the way to control fo R8 is used or not, see https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#enable. Maybe you variant in not release?

same here isMinifyEnabled = false on release has no effect

after a lof searching i found out that you have to also disable
isShrinkResources = false


